# How do I make an inner div's top border overlap the outer div's top border?

Tags: html, css

I have a div within a div and they both have borders. How do I make that inner div's top border overlaps the outer div's border?

HTML:

```
<body>
    <div id = "outerdiv">
        <div id = "innerdiv">
            content
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

CSS:

```
#outerdiv{
    border: 1px solid black;
}

#innerdiv{
    border-top: 1px solid white;
}
```

I want the borders to line up on top of each other so that the inner div would cancel out the bottom border and that section would look like there was a part of the border missing on top.

This works on the bottom border but not on the top.

Comment: What is wrong with this: http://jsfiddle.net/2nXsT/

Comment: That doesn't make the top border disappear with a white background. But thank you anyway

Answer (score 5):

Give your `#innerdiv` a `position:relative; top:-1px`.

Answer (score 1):

It's hacky, but you could shift the element up by `1px`:

```
#innerdiv {
    position: relative;
    top: -1px;

    border-top: 1px solid white;
}
```

**Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/4A8LF/**

Why don't you just add `border-top: 1px solid transparent;` to the parent?

Comment: Because I only want one part of the top border to be missing. Not the whole thing. But thank you.